# How to handle dynamic multiple nested tab layout fragments dynamically?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager, fragment

I have an array of items from an Api, I have to distribute them into multiple tabs group by a sub-item hierarchically.

The number of levels and items are dynamic.

The problem is why tabs load again and again and it takes too long.

Comment: share some codes please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, this may help you

```
ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
private List<Fragment>  fragments;
ArrayList<String> Titles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    Titles= new ArrayList<String>();
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, fragments);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    for (int i=0;i<numoffragments;i++){
            fragments.add(new DemoFragment());

        }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

     }
```

You may need to do some more adjustments to get the numoffragments you will be using and also you have to make a fragment that can be used for all the childs

If your scrolling is too slow you have to set:

```
yourViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(your_tabs_count);
```

hope to be useful.